# jQuery UI SelectMenu - Positioning becomes offset after value change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple fiddle set up that attempts to illustrate this, but essentially what is happening is, using the [jQuery UI SelectMenu plugin](https://raw.github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js) I am having an issue with positioning being drawn improperly whenever I have to programatically tell the SelectMenu to update it's value.

Seen here, I have two boxes. They should both be `250 px` wide, and the first one is. The jQuery SelectMenu plugin does not automatically update to respond to the change in the first, and so I manage this binding via the javascript library `KnockoutJS`. When I programatically inform the select menu that it has changed, I think it is getting completely redrawn and as such is getting very awkward sizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/qgJt7/

can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I think you are making the problem more complicated than it really is...

Is this what you want to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/william/GJuAL/

Comment: Yes but integration with knockout is a requirement.

Comment: I see. In your question you did not make it sound like that: "The jQuery SelectMenu plugin does not automatically update to respond to the change in the first, and so I manage this binding via the javascript library KnockoutJS". I thought you picked up that framework because you wasn't able to make the event working in SelectMenu.

Comment: You are correct. This was a failed communication on my part, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks to your example, I solved this problem. Your example did not provide the actual code it bit showed me how this works under the hood. It occurred to me that I was not re-initializing things properly. So I have solved this by using the "destroy" method that is inherit on all jQuery UI objects.

Comment: It's pushing it to say my answer solved your question....you might want to consider sharing your solution in a proper answer, and simply upvote my answer (as it is helpful). Glad it was useful though :)